# Redirect https://<rootsite>/store to https://store.<rootsite>/

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, apache2

So the structure of my webserver is located at `/var/www/html` and my store directory is at `/var/www/html/store` this is so that I can share resources without using links as it confuses PhPStorm.

I want to force anyone trying to visit `https://<rootsite>/store` to be redirected to `https://store.<rootsite>/`. I have `.htaccess` enabled if that helps, PHP and js.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've tried redirects but it ends up causing the browser to freakout. https://store.<rootsite>/ maps to https://<rootsite>/store in the FS

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's redirect function to get the job done.

```
header('Location: https://store.<rootsite>/');
```

Comment: If I put this in the PHP file, wouldn't it just keep redirecting to the same file over and over again?